# Use case for Exception()

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, exception

Recently I am creating some custom exception and observed that Exception() is present in exception class .I did not understand exact use case for which it is meant for.Because every place any way you will pass a message to inform the cause of exception.

Comment: No, you wouldn't. For example, when Java throws a `NullPointerException`, it doesn't add a message. You understand what the problem was from the type of the Exception and the stack trace.

Comment: If you see in NullPointerException one more overloaded with message is there.But you are correct if I am throwing I can send some message ,if system throwing may be it is not appropriate .

Answer (score 1):

I can think of some use-cases:

- So that subclasses of `Exception` with a no-args constructor have something to chain to.  (`NullPointerException` is an example.)
- For this use-case:

  ```
  StackTraceElement[] trace = new Exception().getStackTrace();
  ```

  That is the classic way that an application method can figure out what method called it.
- When you are using exceptions for "normal" flow control.  (This is nearly always bad practice.)

---

> Because every place any way you will pass a message to inform the cause of exception.

Not true.